# Java recursive/repeated regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all **.**(periods) with keyword **XXX** which lie within an alphanumeric word in a large text.

For example: `I am trying to match a.b.c.d.e ...`
Expected output: `I am trying to match aXXXbXXXcXXXdXXXe ...`

Pattern I used: `(\w+)([\.]+)(\w+)`
Actual result: `I am trying to match aXXXb.cXXXd.e ...`

How can I get **expected output** via regex without using any code/stubs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])", "XXX");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB3hG0/2)

[Lookaround Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks alot Anubhava. Regex worked great:)   I read about lookarounds, their usage may slow down the performance. I have a large documents on which I have to run these sort of regexes. I will give it a try. Thanks again!

Comment: This is one of the simpler lookaround so I don't see performance an issue here.

Comment: I tried lookarounds for 3MB document which is taking around 180secs.      In alternative, I have tried following str = str.replaceAll("((\s|\a|\A|\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.])+([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s|\z|\Z|\b))", "$1XXX$4");  that comes in less than one second. But the issue is same again **(aXXXb.cXXXd.e)**. Can you please suggest an alternate solution with high performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like if you want to change all . -

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.", "XXX");
```

Or below if you don't want to change . if any first or last index -

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.", "XXX").replaceAll("^XXX", ".").replaceAll("XXX$", ".");
```

Comment: Thanks Raman. I am only interested in replacing .(period) with XXX within an **alphanumeric** word, not all periods in a given text.   For example: **Trying to replace a.b.c.d.e  and $.b ....**    Expected output is: **Trying to replace aXXXbXXXcXXXdXXXe  and $.b ....**. Any help would be appreciated.